# How much mana should I put in my deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How much mana should I put in a deck with Mountains and Forests? How much of each? I counted the mana in my black deck to see how much I need, but I still don't know.

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games Stack Exchange! In its current form, this isn't a question we can answer. But you may want to take a look at [this related question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/7589/1910) (short summary: 24 lands is about typical for a 60-card deck).